# javascript execute when text input contains only specific character

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is simulate a user typing something at a prompt and hitting enter.

the live page is at http://www.certified-computer-service.com

the code I currently have looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttons(e){
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    switch(unicode){
        case 49:
            window.alert("1");
            break;
        case 50:
            window.alert("2");
            break;
        case 51:
            window.alert("3");
            break;
        case 52:
            window.alert("4");
            break;
        case 53:
            window.alert("5");
            break;
        case 97:
            window.alert("1");
            break;
        case 98:
            window.alert("2");
            break;
        case 99:
            window.alert("3");
            break;
        case 100:
            window.alert("4");
            break;
        case 101:
            window.alert("5");
            break;
    }
}
</script>

blah blah

<input type="text" name="selection" id="selection" onkeydown="buttons(event); this.select()" style="border: none; background-color: #C0C0C0;">
```

how can I fix this to make it work as intended?  Although the code below won't work, and isn't really written in a language, it's a representation of what I have in mind:

```
inputbox.onKeyup(theKey){
    if theKey == "enter" && inputbox.value == "1" { //respond to key 1 }
    if theKey == "enter" && inputbox.value == "2" { //respond to key 2 }
```

further clarification of my intention can be deducted by looking at the bottom of the mentioned website.

Comment: "how can I fix this to make it work as intended? "  It is not at all clear what you're trying to do.  Please try to clearly state what you're hoping to make this do.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: if you're trying to make pressing "1" on the keyboard trigger a specific link, why not just do that from the javascript you already have (eg `window.location = link[inputbox.value];`)

Comment: ben33 - I stated three times, in different ways what I was trying to accomplish.  Once at the top of the post, once with the "not really code" code, and again by saying look at the site if you still don't get it.  Additionally, other people here have posted and they seemed to know exactly what I was aiming for.  Not my fault you still don't get it.

Offbeatmammal - Yes, I will do exactly that once the other pages are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
 //get the text from the div with jQuery or document.getElementById
 var input = jQuery('#selection').val()
 //you can use a json to map your results or the switch as you described.
 //json example: 
 var json = {1: 'hello', 2: 'world'}
 json['1']
 }
```

Comment: ShiranR - thanks!  It took just a little tinkering, but I didn't have to google anything!